# A tidy and safe way to bundle wires and connect them to terminal posts?

Tags: power-supply, power, wiring

I am building a power supply using an ATX powersupply. There are several wires for each: red for +5V, Yellow for +12V ans so on. The instructions I've seen instruct you to bundle the same colored wires and twist their ends together and then solder them to a binding posts.

I really don't want to do it this way because it is untidy and looks unprofessional. I was hoping to bring all the like wires together and connecting them to a terminal strip and from that strip have a heavier gauge wire that connects to their respective binding post.

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way? Is thereba best practices for auch wiring? Thanks.

Comment: The best practice is just make it look decent and do a good job with the soldering. If you want to make the binding post tidy, you could terminate it into a crimped ring lug after twisting it all together. That will work as long as it doesn't turn out to be too fat.

Comment: You might be able to get that done with one of the yellow crimp lugs that's made for really large gauge wire.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this as well, but was a bit concerned about strength. I tried to do this using one of those all in one cheapo crimping wire cutters and it failed miserably. The lugs pulled off easily,because I couldn't get enough direct crimping force. Since then, I purchased a real ratcheting crimping tool. I will try it again and see if it works better. You should turn your comment into an answer and deck it out with examples. I'll at least give it a vote.

Answer (score 1):

Dupont/Mini PV connectors (made by FCI) are great for connecting wires (22-30awg) to boards. Buy authentic terminals and use the legit crimper (HT-95) if you want quality long lasting work. The ebay stuff will get you by if it is not crucial though.

[check here](http://www.fci.com)

---

This link has a few of what you're describing. Also, you can by jumpers for them to bridge one screw to another.

[terminal strips](http://www.talonix.com/shop/category.aspx?catid=281)

Comment: How about the older screw terminal blocks? The ones with screws on a plastic bar?